# Is some wrong with this call stack in this react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callstack

I was trying to make a stopwatch counter however when I call the "startTimer" function, the setInterval function is fired before the setStartTime (is fired after I click the start button for the second time).

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import RunButton from "./RunButton";

const RunTimer = () => {
    const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
    const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0);
    const [timerTime, setTimerTime] = useState(0);
    const timerInterval = useRef(null);

    const startTimer = () => {
        setTimerOn(true);
        setStartTime(Date.now() - timerTime);
        timerInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
            setTimerTime(Date.now() - startTime);
        }, 1000);
    };

    const stopTimer = () => {
        setTimerOn(false);
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
    };

    const resetTimer = () => {
        setStartTime(0);
        setTimerTime(0);
    };

    let seconds = Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60;
    let minutes = Math.floor(timerTime / 1000 / 60) % 60;

    return (
        <div className="text-6xl font-medium text-center">
            {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:
            {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
            <div className="flex gap-10 justify-around">
                <RunButton title="start" action={startTimer} />
                <RunButton title="stop" color="red" action={stopTimer} />
                <RunButton action={resetTimer} color="yellow" title="reset" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default RunTimer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using Date.now()? Or what is the expected behavior that you are after?

Comment: What is expected is that the Date.now() which return the current time in ms which is set to be the start time when the stopwatch is initialised. After this, the start time will be subtracted from the timer time which results in the ms elapsed since the timer was started (refreshed every second in the set interval() ). What is happening is that the setInterval is being called before setStartTime  - which itself is not being called sometimes. Thus when the seconds and minutes are calculated they return the actual current time rather than the time elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dont understand why you need Date.now() to create a stopwatch.

What is wrong with:

```js
const RunTimer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const timerInterval = useRef(null);

  const startTimer = () => {
    if (!timerInterval.current) {
      timerInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((t) => t + 1000);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerInterval.current);
    timerInterval.current = null;
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTime(0);
  };

  const seconds = Math.floor(time / 1000) % 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 1000 / 60) % 60;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(timerInterval.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="text-6xl font-medium text-center">
      {minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:
      {seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
      <div className="flex gap-10 justify-around">
        <button title="start" onClick={startTimer}>
          start
        </button>
        <button title="start" onClick={stopTimer}>
          stop
        </button>
        <button title="start" onClick={resetTimer}>
          reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, everything is working. Maybe is the Date object was not the right way to go about it. However, I still don't understand why my start timer function failed to implement in the right order.